# Nifi processor is not parsing JSON correctly

Tags: apache-nifi, jsonpath, kylo

I am using EvaluateJsonPath to extract one particular value from JSON. I am using the follwoing  JSONPath expression:

```
 $.data[?(@.containerType == 'SOURCE' && @.path == 'SOURCE_KYLO_DATALAKE')].id
```

This is the JSON document I'm calling the JSONPath on :

```
{"data":[{"id":"dc18bf87-c5a6-4600-9584-e79fb988b1d0","path":["@Rakesh.Prasad@diageo.com"],"tag":"0","type":"CONTAINER","containerType":"HOME"},{"id":"42e52055-4deb-4d5d-942f-4e1c4e48c35e","path":["BPM"],"tag":"3","type":"CONTAINER","containerType":"SPACE"},{"id":"49e3d118-e4f9-41ef-ad97-6b2745c75c4f","path":["DATABRICKS_USAGE_REPORT"],"tag":"0","type":"CONTAINER","containerType":"SPACE"},{"id":"613f52e9-64df-4c9c-b083-c282f349eb4e","path":["LIGHTHOUSE"],"tag":"3","type":"CONTAINER","containerType":"SPACE"},{"id":"f57bcd83-4d0e-481e-b880-0fb8b20798a1","path":["MDM"],"tag":"2","type":"CONTAINER","containerType":"SPACE"},{"id":"745cd2d5-7303-4c0a-9cab-f5205b9eec90","path":["NIELSEN"],"tag":"2","type":"CONTAINER","containerType":"SPACE"},{"id":"b40da338-c429-4bb3-b2ef-51295a143fc8","path":["PowerBI"],"tag":"0","type":"CONTAINER","containerType":"SPACE"},{"id":"dffd025c-b0f0-4b9b-9060-da4aa54204d1","path":["REFERENCE_DATA"],"tag":"1","type":"CONTAINER","containerType":"SPACE"},{"id":"14f9759a-2059-4728-acad-fe01f129f148","path":["SAP_ODP_MASTERDATA"],"tag":"1","type":"CONTAINER","containerType":"SPACE"},{"id":"063bb5e8-041a-4f69-98a3-d2509d5e89d0","path":["TRAX"],"tag":"1","type":"CONTAINER","containerType":"SPACE"},{"id":"9c737147-6632-4328-bf10-ba4959a2806f","path":["TRAX_API"],"tag":"0","type":"CONTAINER","containerType":"SPACE"},{"id":"99167858-17ca-406f-b887-62af3d0da68a","path":["DEPLETION"],"tag":"1","type":"CONTAINER","containerType":"SPACE"},{"id":"52f17de1-a66e-4f08-9077-04acf3914663","path":["SOURCE_ADLS_NIELSEN_PROD"],"tag":"1","type":"CONTAINER","containerType":"SOURCE"},{"id":"bea0de9c-b579-46bd-89ff-4b9497c3910e","path":["SOURCE_KYLO_DATALAKE"],"tag":"5","type":"CONTAINER","containerType":"SOURCE"},{"id":"20985e83-cd31-469e-9a17-1e586bccfb27","path":["SOURCE_LIGHTHOUSE_UAT"],"tag":"1","type":"CONTAINER","containerType":"SOURCE"},{"id":"47406901-c9ce-4fce-b0ab-37b07338949b","path":["SOURCE_MDM_UAT"],"tag":"1","type":"CONTAINER","containerType":"SOURCE"},{"id":"f1feff7d-8ada-46bb-a5fe-0283a2c746b3","path":["SOURCE_MDS_UAT"],"tag":"0","type":"CONTAINER","containerType":"SOURCE"},{"id":"48a5d1b6-8d32-449d-a317-d242f2394e71","path":["SOURCE_NIELSEN_UAT"],"tag":"1","type":"CONTAINER","containerType":"SOURCE"},{"id":"32eaeeb5-60d5-4d87-a983-1e71e3543920","path":["SOURCE_PROD_BPM"],"tag":"1","type":"CONTAINER","containerType":"SOURCE"},{"id":"f4af00a5-a536-4272-93cb-891ec13ef8e4","path":["SOURCE_SAP_MDS_STAGING"],"tag":"3","type":"CONTAINER","containerType":"SOURCE"},{"id":"7250d605-75a9-4ef2-a01b-55c2bcb44dd9","path":["SOURCE_TRAX_UAT"],"tag":"1","type":"CONTAINER","containerType":"SOURCE"},{"id":"38a8293e-72f4-42c2-be66-667b21a1ac55","path":["SOURCE_KYLO_HIVE2"],"tag":"10","type":"CONTAINER","containerType":"SOURCE"},{"id":"95cb9f2f-3421-451a-8635-bb8487dc1872","path":["dwlprd1"],"tag":"7","type":"CONTAINER","containerType":"SOURCE"},{"id":"ac9334e4-daf2-4c6f-92f1-0452440fb737","path":["dwlprd2"],"tag":"5","type":"CONTAINER","containerType":"SOURCE"},{"id":"c27af9bd-075b-4fb8-bcd4-8450f26ff7f9","path":["SOURCE_ADLS_NIELSEN_DEPLETION_UAT"],"tag":"1","type":"CONTAINER","containerType":"SOURCE"}]}
```

When I use the configuration(that specific JSONPath query) from above on a JSONPath online testing tool (see attached image), I get the expected result. But somehow nifi is returning empty array.

[image]

Template:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><template encoding-version="1.2"><description></description><groupId>ae48862f-0165-1000-cc45-c1efcbb7ff08</groupId><name>dnu_jsonpath</name><snippet><connections><id>d84c0b8e-6983-3f0e-0000-000000000000</id><parentGroupId>5842a0b1-f01b-3160-0000-000000000000</parentGroupId><backPressureDataSizeThreshold>1 GB</backPressureDataSizeThreshold><backPressureObjectThreshold>10000</backPressureObjectThreshold><destination><groupId>5842a0b1-f01b-3160-0000-000000000000</groupId><id>7d993abd-1c1e-3cc5-0000-000000000000</id><type>PROCESSOR</type></destination><flowFileExpiration>0 sec</flowFileExpiration><labelIndex>1</labelIndex><name></name><selectedRelationships>success</selectedRelationships><source><groupId>5842a0b1-f01b-3160-0000-000000000000</groupId><id>509810d8-4798-30e5-0000-000000000000</id><type>PROCESSOR</type></source><zIndex>0</zIndex></connections><connections><id>02ff8ff3-ed1e-34b1-0000-000000000000</id><parentGroupId>5842a0b1-f01b-3160-0000-000000000000</parentGroupId><backPressureDataSizeThreshold>1 GB</backPressureDataSizeThreshold><backPressureObjectThreshold>10000</backPressureObjectThreshold><destination><groupId>5842a0b1-f01b-3160-0000-000000000000</groupId><id>8d45c558-a4a7-3529-0000-000000000000</id><type>PROCESSOR</type></destination><flowFileExpiration>0 sec</flowFileExpiration><labelIndex>1</labelIndex><name></name><selectedRelationships>failure</selectedRelationships><selectedRelationships>unmatched</selectedRelationships><source><groupId>5842a0b1-f01b-3160-0000-000000000000</groupId><id>7d993abd-1c1e-3cc5-0000-000000000000</id><type>PROCESSOR</type></source><zIndex>0</zIndex></connections><connections><id>6a3afe0c-951a-33fc-0000-000000000000</id><parentGroupId>5842a0b1-f01b-3160-0000-000000000000</parentGroupId><backPressureDataSizeThreshold>1 GB</backPressureDataSizeThreshold><backPressureObjectThreshold>10000</backPressureObjectThreshold><destination><groupId>5842a0b1-f01b-3160-0000-000000000000</groupId><id>ab89e6d1-f08e-32be-0000-000000000000</id><type>PROCESSOR</type></destination><flowFileExpiration>0 sec</flowFileExpiration><labelIndex>1</labelIndex><name></name><selectedRelationships>matched</selectedRelationships><source><groupId>5842a0b1-f01b-3160-0000-000000000000</groupId><id>7d993abd-1c1e-3cc5-0000-000000000000</id><type>PROCESSOR</type></source><zIndex>0</zIndex></connections><processors><id>8d45c558-a4a7-3529-0000-000000000000</id><parentGroupId>5842a0b1-f01b-3160-0000-000000000000</parentGroupId><position><x>607.0</x><y>151.0</y></position><bundle><artifact>nifi-standard-nar</artifact><group>org.apache.nifi</group><version>1.6.0</version></bundle><config><bulletinLevel>WARN</bulletinLevel><comments></comments><concurrentlySchedulableTaskCount>1</concurrentlySchedulableTaskCount><descriptors><entry><key>Log Level</key><value><name>Log Level</name></value></entry><entry><key>Log Payload</key><value><name>Log Payload</name></value></entry><entry><key>Attributes to Log</key><value><name>Attributes to Log</name></value></entry><entry><key>attributes-to-log-regex</key><value><name>attributes-to-log-regex</name></value></entry><entry><key>Attributes to Ignore</key><value><name>Attributes to Ignore</name></value></entry><entry><key>attributes-to-ignore-regex</key><value><name>attributes-to-ignore-regex</name></value></entry><entry><key>Log prefix</key><value><name>Log prefix</name></value></entry><entry><key>character-set</key><value><name>character-set</name></value></entry></descriptors><executionNode>ALL</executionNode><lossTolerant>false</lossTolerant><penaltyDuration>30 sec</penaltyDuration><properties><entry><key>Log Level</key><value>info</value></entry><entry><key>Log Payload</key><value>false</value></entry><entry><key>Attributes to Log</key></entry><entry><key>attributes-to-log-regex</key><value>.*</value></entry><entry><key>Attributes to Ignore</key></entry><entry><key>attributes-to-ignore-regex</key></entry><entry><key>Log prefix</key></entry><entry><key>character-set</key><value>UTF-8</value></entry></properties><runDurationMillis>0</runDurationMillis><schedulingPeriod>0 sec</schedulingPeriod><schedulingStrategy>TIMER_DRIVEN</schedulingStrategy><yieldDuration>1 sec</yieldDuration></config><name>LogAttribute</name><relationships><autoTerminate>false</autoTerminate><name>success</name></relationships><state>STOPPED</state><style/><type>org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.LogAttribute</type></processors><processors><id>ab89e6d1-f08e-32be-0000-000000000000</id><parentGroupId>5842a0b1-f01b-3160-0000-000000000000</parentGroupId><position><x>715.0</x><y>468.99999999999994</y></position><bundle><artifact>nifi-standard-nar</artifact><group>org.apache.nifi</group><version>1.6.0</version></bundle><config><bulletinLevel>WARN</bulletinLevel><comments></comments><concurrentlySchedulableTaskCount>1</concurrentlySchedulableTaskCount><descriptors><entry><key>Log Level</key><value><name>Log Level</name></value></entry><entry><key>Log Payload</key><value><name>Log Payload</name></value></entry><entry><key>Attributes to Log</key><value><name>Attributes to Log</name></value></entry><entry><key>attributes-to-log-regex</key><value><name>attributes-to-log-regex</name></value></entry><entry><key>Attributes to Ignore</key><value><name>Attributes to Ignore</name></value></entry><entry><key>attributes-to-ignore-regex</key><value><name>attributes-to-ignore-regex</name></value></entry><entry><key>Log prefix</key><value><name>Log prefix</name></value></entry><entry><key>character-set</key><value><name>character-set</name></value></entry></descriptors><executionNode>ALL</executionNode><lossTolerant>false</lossTolerant><penaltyDuration>30 sec</penaltyDuration><properties><entry><key>Log Level</key><value>info</value></entry><entry><key>Log Payload</key><value>false</value></entry><entry><key>Attributes to Log</key></entry><entry><key>attributes-to-log-regex</key><value>.*</value></entry><entry><key>Attributes to Ignore</key></entry><entry><key>attributes-to-ignore-regex</key></entry><entry><key>Log prefix</key></entry><entry><key>character-set</key><value>UTF-8</value></entry></properties><runDurationMillis>0</runDurationMillis><schedulingPeriod>0 sec</schedulingPeriod><schedulingStrategy>TIMER_DRIVEN</schedulingStrategy><yieldDuration>1 sec</yieldDuration></config><name>LogAttribute</name><relationships><autoTerminate>false</autoTerminate><name>success</name></relationships><state>STOPPED</state><style/><type>org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.LogAttribute</type></processors><processors><id>509810d8-4798-30e5-0000-000000000000</id><parentGroupId>5842a0b1-f01b-3160-0000-000000000000</parentGroupId><position><x>0.0</x><y>0.0</y></position><bundle><artifact>nifi-standard-nar</artifact><group>org.apache.nifi</group><version>1.6.0</version></bundle><config><bulletinLevel>WARN</bulletinLevel><comments></comments><concurrentlySchedulableTaskCount>1</concurrentlySchedulableTaskCount><descriptors><entry><key>File Size</key><value><name>File Size</name></value></entry><entry><key>Batch Size</key><value><name>Batch Size</name></value></entry><entry><key>Data Format</key><value><name>Data Format</name></value></entry><entry><key>Unique FlowFiles</key><value><name>Unique FlowFiles</name></value></entry><entry><key>generate-ff-custom-text</key><value><name>generate-ff-custom-text</name></value></entry><entry><key>character-set</key><value><name>character-set</name></value></entry></descriptors><executionNode>ALL</executionNode><lossTolerant>false</lossTolerant><penaltyDuration>30 sec</penaltyDuration><properties><entry><key>File Size</key><value>0B</value></entry><entry><key>Batch Size</key><value>1</value></entry><entry><key>Data Format</key><value>Text</value></entry><entry><key>Unique FlowFiles</key><value>false</value></entry><entry><key>generate-ff-custom-text</key><value>{"data":[{"id":"dc18bf87-c5a6-4600-9584-e79fb988b1d0","path":["@Rakesh.Prasad@diageo.com"],"tag":"0","type":"CONTAINER","containerType":"HOME"},{"id":"42e52055-4deb-4d5d-942f-4e1c4e48c35e","path":["BPM"],"tag":"3","type":"CONTAINER","containerType":"SPACE"},{"id":"49e3d118-e4f9-41ef-ad97-6b2745c75c4f","path":["DATABRICKS_USAGE_REPORT"],"tag":"0","type":"CONTAINER","containerType":"SPACE"},{"id":"613f52e9-64df-4c9c-b083-c282f349eb4e","path":["LIGHTHOUSE"],"tag":"3","type":"CONTAINER","containerType":"SPACE"},{"id":"f57bcd83-4d0e-481e-b880-0fb8b20798a1","path":["MDM"],"tag":"2","type":"CONTAINER","containerType":"SPACE"},{"id":"745cd2d5-7303-4c0a-9cab-f5205b9eec90","path":["NIELSEN"],"tag":"2","type":"CONTAINER","containerType":"SPACE"},{"id":"b40da338-c429-4bb3-b2ef-51295a143fc8","path":["PowerBI"],"tag":"0","type":"CONTAINER","containerType":"SPACE"},{"id":"dffd025c-b0f0-4b9b-9060-da4aa54204d1","path":["REFERENCE_DATA"],"tag":"1","type":"CONTAINER","containerType":"SPACE"},{"id":"14f9759a-2059-4728-acad-fe01f129f148","path":["SAP_ODP_MASTERDATA"],"tag":"1","type":"CONTAINER","containerType":"SPACE"},{"id":"063bb5e8-041a-4f69-98a3-d2509d5e89d0","path":["TRAX"],"tag":"1","type":"CONTAINER","containerType":"SPACE"},{"id":"9c737147-6632-4328-bf10-ba4959a2806f","path":["TRAX_API"],"tag":"0","type":"CONTAINER","containerType":"SPACE"},{"id":"99167858-17ca-406f-b887-62af3d0da68a","path":["DEPLETION"],"tag":"1","type":"CONTAINER","containerType":"SPACE"},{"id":"52f17de1-a66e-4f08-9077-04acf3914663","path":["SOURCE_ADLS_NIELSEN_PROD"],"tag":"1","type":"CONTAINER","containerType":"SOURCE"},{"id":"bea0de9c-b579-46bd-89ff-4b9497c3910e","path":["SOURCE_KYLO_DATALAKE"],"tag":"5","type":"CONTAINER","containerType":"SOURCE"},{"id":"20985e83-cd31-469e-9a17-1e586bccfb27","path":["SOURCE_LIGHTHOUSE_UAT"],"tag":"1","type":"CONTAINER","containerType":"SOURCE"},{"id":"47406901-c9ce-4fce-b0ab-37b07338949b","path":["SOURCE_MDM_UAT"],"tag":"1","type":"CONTAINER","containerType":"SOURCE"},{"id":"f1feff7d-8ada-46bb-a5fe-0283a2c746b3","path":["SOURCE_MDS_UAT"],"tag":"0","type":"CONTAINER","containerType":"SOURCE"},{"id":"48a5d1b6-8d32-449d-a317-d242f2394e71","path":["SOURCE_NIELSEN_UAT"],"tag":"1","type":"CONTAINER","containerType":"SOURCE"},{"id":"32eaeeb5-60d5-4d87-a983-1e71e3543920","path":["SOURCE_PROD_BPM"],"tag":"1","type":"CONTAINER","containerType":"SOURCE"},{"id":"f4af00a5-a536-4272-93cb-891ec13ef8e4","path":["SOURCE_SAP_MDS_STAGING"],"tag":"3","type":"CONTAINER","containerType":"SOURCE"},{"id":"7250d605-75a9-4ef2-a01b-55c2bcb44dd9","path":["SOURCE_TRAX_UAT"],"tag":"1","type":"CONTAINER","containerType":"SOURCE"},{"id":"38a8293e-72f4-42c2-be66-667b21a1ac55","path":["SOURCE_KYLO_HIVE2"],"tag":"10","type":"CONTAINER","containerType":"SOURCE"},{"id":"95cb9f2f-3421-451a-8635-bb8487dc1872","path":["dwlprd1"],"tag":"7","type":"CONTAINER","containerType":"SOURCE"},{"id":"ac9334e4-daf2-4c6f-92f1-0452440fb737","path":["dwlprd2"],"tag":"5","type":"CONTAINER","containerType":"SOURCE"},{"id":"c27af9bd-075b-4fb8-bcd4-8450f26ff7f9","path":["SOURCE_ADLS_NIELSEN_DEPLETION_UAT"],"tag":"1","type":"CONTAINER","containerType":"SOURCE"}]}</value></entry><entry><key>character-set</key><value>UTF-8</value></entry></properties><runDurationMillis>0</runDurationMillis><schedulingPeriod>1 day</schedulingPeriod><schedulingStrategy>TIMER_DRIVEN</schedulingStrategy><yieldDuration>1 sec</yieldDuration></config><name>GenerateFlowFile</name><relationships><autoTerminate>false</autoTerminate><name>success</name></relationships><state>STOPPED</state><style/><type>org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.GenerateFlowFile</type></processors><processors><id>7d993abd-1c1e-3cc5-0000-000000000000</id><parentGroupId>5842a0b1-f01b-3160-0000-000000000000</parentGroupId><position><x>107.0</x><y>256.0</y></position><bundle><artifact>nifi-standard-nar</artifact><group>org.apache.nifi</group><version>1.6.0</version></bundle><config><bulletinLevel>WARN</bulletinLevel><comments></comments><concurrentlySchedulableTaskCount>1</concurrentlySchedulableTaskCount><descriptors><entry><key>Destination</key><value><name>Destination</name></value></entry><entry><key>Return Type</key><value><name>Return Type</name></value></entry><entry><key>Path Not Found Behavior</key><value><name>Path Not Found Behavior</name></value></entry><entry><key>Null Value Representation</key><value><name>Null Value Representation</name></value></entry><entry><key>dataset</key><value><name>dataset</name></value></entry></descriptors><executionNode>ALL</executionNode><lossTolerant>false</lossTolerant><penaltyDuration>30 sec</penaltyDuration><properties><entry><key>Destination</key><value>flowfile-content</value></entry><entry><key>Return Type</key><value>auto-detect</value></entry><entry><key>Path Not Found Behavior</key><value>warn</value></entry><entry><key>Null Value Representation</key><value>empty string</value></entry><entry><key>dataset</key><value>$.data[?(@.containerType == "SOURCE" &amp;&amp; @.path == "SOURCE_KYLO_DATALAKE")].id</value></entry></properties><runDurationMillis>0</runDurationMillis><schedulingPeriod>0 sec</schedulingPeriod><schedulingStrategy>TIMER_DRIVEN</schedulingStrategy><yieldDuration>1 sec</yieldDuration></config><name>EvaluateJsonPath</name><relationships><autoTerminate>false</autoTerminate><name>failure</name></relationships><relationships><autoTerminate>false</autoTerminate><name>matched</name></relationships><relationships><autoTerminate>false</autoTerminate><name>unmatched</name></relationships><state>STOPPED</state><style/><type>org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.EvaluateJsonPath</type></processors></snippet><timestamp>09/24/2018 06:03:42 EDT</timestamp></template>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you are searching for value in **path** array, Enclose `SOURCE_KYLO_DATALAKE` in `[](array)` then processor will only result the matching id value as output content.

Change the Eval JsonPath property value as below

**dataset**

> ```
> $.data[?(@.containerType == 'SOURCE' && @.path == ['SOURCE_KYLO_DATALAKE'])].id
> ```

***Configs:***
[image]

***Output Flowfile Content:***

```
["bea0de9c-b579-46bd-89ff-4b9497c3910e"]
```

> ***UPDATE:***

I have used NiFi-1.7.1 and EvaluateJson expression works fine in this version.

However if you are using other versions of NiFi then

1.if you are having `only one element` in array then use below expression in your EvaluateJsonPath processor.

**dataset**

```
$.data[?(@.containerType == 'SOURCE'  && @.path[0] == 'SOURCE_KYLO_DATALAKE')].id
```

2.If you are having more than one element in array then

**Flow:**

[image]

**Flow Description:**

1.`SplitJson`

- to split data array into individual messages
- configure JsonPathExpression to
  `$.data`

2.`EvaluateJsonPath`

- To extract required content and keep as attribute to the flowfile
  [image]
  Now we are having **id,containerType,path** values as attributes to the flowfile

3.`RouteOnAttribute`:

- in this processor we are checking the attribute values using NiFi expression language
- Add new property as

  **required**

  `${containerType:equals("SOURCE"):and(${anyDelineatedValue("${path:replace('[',''):replace(']','')}",","):equals('"SOURCE_KYLO_DATALAKE"')})}`

[image]

Feed the required relationship to ReplaceText processor

4.`ReplaceText`

- Now we are replacing the id values to the flowfile content

[image]

Now we are going to have the id value in your output flowfile content from ReplaceText processor.

If possible upgrade the **NiFi version to 1.7.1** then you don't need to do all these workarounds :)

Comment: which version of nifi r u using? i am on 1.6. It seems i am not able to filter on path. as soon as I put that in filter, I am getting blank array.

Comment: @RakeshPrasad, I'm able to reproduce the same issue in NiFi 1.6, Please check my updated answer's **update section**, That will resolve your issue i believe.

Comment: I wish I could, but Nifi is part of Kylo, in our environment. and kylo doesn't support 1.7 yet. But thanks for detailed answer. Thanks