# How can I filter flow files upon the result of an SQL query?

Tags: apache-nifi

Would it be possible to route flow files according to the result of an SQL query which returns a single row result? For example, if the result is '1' the flow file will be processed; otherwise, it will be ignored.

### Solution

The following approach worked best for me.

1. Use **ExecuteSQL** processor in order to run filtering SQL query. The query was written to produce either a single record (match) or an empty record set (no match) in a way suggested by Shu.
2. Connect **ExecuteSQL** to  **RouteOnAttribute** processor in order to filter out unmatched flow files using the following value of routing property value `${executesql.row.count:replaceNull(0):gt(0)}`

**Notice**, that the original content of a flow file will be lost after applying **ExecuteSQL**. It's not an issue in my case, because I do filtering before processing flow file content and my SQL query is based entirely on the flow file attributes and not on its content. Though in a more general scenario, when the flow file content is modified by the incoming part of the flow, one should save file content somewhere (e.g. file system) and restore it after the filtering part has applied.

Answer (score 2):

You can **add where clause** in your sql query `where <field_name> = 1` then we are only going to have output a **flowfile** when the **result value =1**.

(or)

***Checking the data in NiFi:***

We are going to have **AVRO** format data as the result of SQL query so you can use

> ***option1:ConvertAvroToJson Processor:***

Convert the **AVRO** data into **JSON** format then extract the value from the **json content as attribute using EvaluateJsonPath processor.**

Then use **RouteOnAttribute** processor add new property using [NiFi expression language equals function](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/expression-language-guide.html#equals) compare the value and route the flowfile to matched relation.

Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52477093/nifi-processor-is-not-parsing-json-correctly/52478476#52478476) link more details regards to EvaluateJsonpath and RouteOnAttribute processor configs.

> ***option2: Using QueryRecord processor:***

By using **QueryRecord** processor we can run **SQL queries** on the content of the flowfile

Add new property to the processor as

```
select * from FLOWFILE where <filed_name> =1
```

Feed the property relation to the other processor

Refer to [this](https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/121794/running-sql-on-flowfiles-using-queryrecord-process.html) link for more details regarding QueryRecord processor usage.

Comment: Definitely use option 2

Comment: Thanks for suggestions. I added the solution that worked best for me to the question.